# Can't find MultiFormatReader class in zxing core.jar file

Tags: java, jar, jruby, zxing

I'm trying to use a more current version of zxing and have tried replacing the `core.jar` and `javase.jar` files from the [ecin/zxing gem](https://github.com/ecin/zxing.rb/tree/master/lib/zxing) with the 3.0 snapshot versions of those files from https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/zxing/core/

I'm getting a `NameError` on the first class I try to reference (`com/google/zxing/MultiFormatReader` from the `core.jar` file) even though the class shows up in the new jar when I do a `jar -tf`. The software runs file with the old jar files.

Any suggestions on how to debug this further?

**Update**: I created a new gemset with a Gemfile with only zxing in it and reproduced the same behavior, as shown below.

```
MacbookAir1:javlats2 palfvin$ irb
jruby-1.7.10 :001 > require 'zxing'
NameError: missing class or uppercase package name (`com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader')
    from org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:54:in `get_proxy_or_package_under_package'
    from file:/Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.10/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/java_package_module_template.rb:14:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.10@javlats2/gems/zxing-0.3.1/lib/zxing/decoder.rb:12:in `ZXing'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.10@javlats2/gems/zxing-0.3.1/lib/zxing/decoder.rb:3:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1083:in `require'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1:in `(root)'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1083:in `require'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.10@javlats2/gems/zxing-0.3.1/lib/zxing.rb:2:in `(root)'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1119:in `eval'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from (irb):1:in `evaluate'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1519:in `loop'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1282:in `catch'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1282:in `catch'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.10/bin/irb:13:in `(root)'jruby-1.7.10 :002 >
```

Comment: Has the location of core.jar changed any? Make sure its location is in your classpath.

Comment: It is most certainly there. You are probably not actually including the jar file in your classpath.

Comment: @Alan No, I haven't made any changes whatsoever. The application runs fine with the old jar files.

Comment: @SeanOwen As I said in the question, the application runs fine with the old jar files. If I only change the jar files, it fails in the manner I indicated. If I restore the old jar files, it runs fine again.

Comment: Of course. And you realize the new jar has the same class in the same place. Ergo, something is wrong with how you include new jar, not old jar. But both jars are fine themselves.

Comment: @SeanOwen But the new jar has the same name as the old jar. I did exactly what is shown in the answer below.

Comment: @SeanOwen See my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This session worked from IRB, so the class is present in the new version of the JAR:

```
> require 'core-3.0.0-20140213.213916-7.jar'
> com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.new
 => #<Java::ComGoogleZxing::MultiFormatReader:0x6e644f41>
```

My guess is that you haven't replaced the JAR in the right way, somehow. I did this to "upgrade" the JAR:

```
pushd ~/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.10/gems/zxing-0.3.1/lib/zxing/
mv core.jar orig.jar
mv ~/Downloads/core-3.0.0-20140213.213916-7.jar core.jar
```

Then was able to do this:

```
> require 'zxing'
> ZXing.decode 'http://2d-code.co.uk/images/bbc-logo-in-qr-code.gif'
 => "http://bbc.co.uk/programmes"
```

I don't know the difference between the 2.x and 3.x APIs to be sure, but I can certainly drop in the new JAR over the old one.

Comment: There is no difference in this class at all, yes.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for your efforts on this. I updated my question to show the specifics I'm seeing. I replaced the jar files exactly as you did using a separate gemset.

Comment: @Shepmaster I was also able to reproduce the problem with CRuby 2.0

Comment: @Shepmaster +1 for trying this out. See my answer for additional info.

Answer (score 0):

I turns out this was related to the version of Java pointed to by my PATH variable. Even though I'd long ago installed version 7 on my mac, I'd never updated my `.bash_profile` and was picking up 6 for various command line operations. After I changed my PATH to point to 7, the problem went away.

There are still a few mysteries that remain, however, as follows:

- When I posted my question, there were jar files in the [zxing snapshot directories](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/zxing/) named (`-6.jar`) as if they were built for version 6, but they are no longer there (less than 24 hours later)
- When I tried those `-6.jar` files, they failed as well
- I can't find anything on the web about general incompatibility between Java 6 and Java 7 that would explain the error I was getting